# Sharing External Drive using Samba in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, permissions, mount, hard-drive, samba

I have a small home network of 3 computers, each running Ubuntu 18.04. Up until some very recent update I was able to share external drives attached to each of the machines across that network... now no more, and I don't know why. Very frustrated... I'm not a computer wiz at all, and this seems like it should be a very simple thing but I can't get the drives to mount on other computers in the network even though they appear as available. I get a permissions denied error.

So how do I set up a config for this so that there are NO permissions required for an external drive... anybody could anonymously mount that drive on their desktop. Gotta be a way to do this. I've tried all the old tutorials I can find, but just make a mess of things. I kinda need step by step instructions for this issue specifically.

testparm -s results

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Processing section "[print$]"
Processing section "[public]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
```

## Global parameters

```
[global]
    dns proxy = No
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    syslog = 0
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    usershare owner only = No
    idmap config * : backend = tdb


[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[public]
    comment = public anonymous access
    create mask = 0660
    directory mask = 0771
    guest ok = Yes
    path = /var/samba/
    read only = No

net usershare info --long results

[Anime A-M]
path=/media/jaxes/Anime A-M
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=y

info_fn: file /var/lib/samba/usershares/cinema a-m is not a well formed usershare file.
info_fn: Error was Path is not a directory.
info_fn: file /var/lib/samba/usershares/free is not a well formed usershare file.
info_fn: Error was Path is not a directory.
[Anime N-Z]
path=/media/jaxes/Anime N-Z
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=y

[Public]
path=/home/jaxes/Public
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=y
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 shares named "Public" that point to 2 differnt paths ( /var/samba and /home/jaxes/Public ). Samba is confused.

I would remove the one you have in /etc/samba/smb.conf or at least rename it to say ... [public2].

Then in order to access the [Anime N-Z] share you will need to go back to what I recommended originally: Right under the "workgroup = WORKGROUP" line add this one:

```
force user = jaxes
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Comment: That didn't work... now I can't even access the shared Public folder remotely. Plus I know that two weeks ago when this was still working, I didn't have that line in the config file. There was some update about two weeks ago that required a restart (nothing unusual in that) and after the restart I got the permission denied error. I can see all the drives on every machine, I just can't access them anymore. And before this, I could always access them remotely as an anonymous user with no password (which is what I want... no security concerns it's purely an internal network with no wireless).

Comment: Not enough information to answer the question. Please add to your original question the output of the following commands - without quotes: "testparm -s" and "net usershare info --long".

Comment: added testparm and net usershare to original question per request

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect the new data provided.

Comment: followed suggestion for public and anime n-z drive, and now I can't even get anything to open on the other machines... I don't even get the popup asking for the anonymous logon or logon using a password. I get 'failed to retrieve sharelist from server' error message when I click on the computer in the other locations menu

Comment: You will not get that error from what I posted above. You should post your question in the ubuntu forums.

Comment: Thanks Morbius... actually you were a big help. I think after trying so many different things to get this to work, I has so screwed up the Samba settings that just correcting the conf was not enough. I ended up doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and Samba, THEN applied your suggested edits to the conf, to get it to work. Still don't know what screwed up the settings or samba to make this happen in the first place, but it's back to working correctly now. Just had to reinstall OS and Samba, and make the edits you suggested. Gotta be an easier way...